# Blender not Running using Nvidia Graphics But Run using Integrated Graphics

Tags: rendering

[image: Integerated Graphic Running]

[image: Nvidia 940MX Setting not Running]

It can be clearly seen in Image 1 that Blender is running in integrated Graphics but when i turn my settings to High Performance Nvidia Graphics i.e Nvidia 940MX, Blender stucks at the white screen and do not move further. i tried waiting for more than 20 minutes. 
My Laptop model is HP- Pavilion 15-cc0xx with 4 GB dedicated Graphic card and 4GB integrated .. Kindly guide me..

Comment: Best to report a bug in the bug tracker. Developer.blender.org

Comment: Try updating your graphics drivers to the latest version; reinstall Blender, and clear settings to factory default. Your card is also on the lower end of the spectrum, so it is not very powerful and may lead to issues. Otherwise as stated it sounds like a bug report, **IF** your are able and willing to provide detailed debugging info to the developers.

Comment: If nothing works, also check if an older blender version works. Gpu compatibilty evolves with versions, older cards are less supported.

Answer (score 1):

i have the same laptop and have found i had exactly the same problem, and it was driving me nuts! but i'm pleased to say i've found a work around... its a bit hacky but it works, and it seems to be the only thing that does.

The laptop is delivered with both the intel UHD 620 graphics and also the geforce 940MX enabled. you need to disable the intel GPU in device manager, and this stops any conflicts between the two GPUs when launching blender.

First right click on the windows icon in the bottom left of your screen, and select the option for 'device manager'. In the new window that comes up, expand the tree at 'display adaptors'. you will see there are two graphics adaptors enabled, the intel adaptor, and the nvidia adaptor. right click on the intel adaptor and select 'disable device'.

[image: Device manager showing the two adaptors enabled]

Testing: be aware that although this works flawlessly for blender, there are other software packages that i have installed on my laptop which require both adaptors to be enabled, the intel adaptor only to be enabled, or the nvidia adaptor only to be enabled. also in some software i have found the CPU works twice as hard when the nvidia adaptor is being used. (I assume there are some efficiencies in having the GPU integrated with the intel CPU which you give up when you move to the nvidia adaptor).

In any case, its still a bit of a pain, but this should get you going with blender again. Hopefully various updates will address the issue in the fullness of time. in the meantime, just keep the above notes in mind should any of your other software packages stop working.