# Blender keeps using my CPU for rendering even though I have only my GPU enabled for CUDA

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

So I checked many answers and none of them worked. I have a laptop (gtx 930M and i3-5010U). Things I already did -
Selected GPU Compute in Scene property 
Select only my GPU under CUDA in Cycle Render Engine in System settings.

Yet when I render my CPU utilization goes up to 100% and my temps too while my GPU has hardly 20% Utilization. I also see 4 boxes while rendering (I've heard if its CPU the different cores render them and my i3 has 4 cores).

Comment: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99673/blender-not-running-using-nvidia-graphics-but-run-using-integrated-graphics) either? It is probably cause by the integrated GPU

Comment: Not really. Although when I go to settings and uncheck all and select only my GPU I does render using my GPU but I have to repeat the said process everytime I open blender or else it would still render in CPU

Comment: Did you save the preference after choosing GPU? In old 2.80 setting won't be automatic save until user check that option.